# Conditional Probability Question: Cards to be chosen at random

Tags: probability

A boy has 2 boxes. Box A contains 4 red cards and 3 green cards and box B contains a red card and 2 green cards. A card is randomly drawn from box A and placed in box B. Then a card is drawn from box B. Find the probability that

(a) the card drawn from box A and the card drawn from box B are both green

(b) a green card is drawn from box B

I got the answer for (a) being $\frac{3}{7} \cdot \frac{3}{4} = \frac{9}{28}$

But I cant get the answer for (b), as it is given answer is $\frac{17}{28}$ ?

Comment: Try writing $P(\text{green card from B})=P(\text{green card from A and green card from B})+P(\text{red card from A and green card from B})$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

b)

Each of the $3$ green cards originally in box $A$ has probability $\frac17\times\frac14$ to become the drawn card.

Each of the $2$ green cards originally in box $B$ has probability $\frac14$ to become the drawn card.

These $5$ events are mutually exclusive and the union of these events is exactly the event that a green card is drawn. We conclude that: $$\Pr(\text{a green card is drawn})=3\times\frac17\times\frac14+2\times\frac14=\frac{17}{28}$$

A basic method.